# Calling SendMessage returns 32 bit result in a 64 bit environment

Tags: windows, delphi, 64-bit, sendmessage

I am converting a Delphi Windows program to 64 bit. When I use SendMessage to send a EM_LINEINDEX message to a component it should return -1 if the WPARAM parameter is greater than the number of lines of text in the component.
But it returns $FFFFFFFF (-1 in 32 bit format). So a comparison with -1 fails.

It is easy to demonstrate, just build a VCL app with a form containing a TMemo and a TButton
Add the following buttonclick code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  x: int64;
begin
   x:=SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, WPARAM(5), 0);
   ShowMessage(Format('%d  %X',[x,x]));
end;
```

The string displayed is: 4294967295  FFFFFFFF

Stepping through the assembly code I see it returns 00000000FFFFFFF in rax.

If change the variable x to be an integer, it works, but if range checking is turned on (using  {$R+}) it throws a range error exception which is how I found it in the first place.

Should I expect 32 bit results from all Windows messages in a 64 bit environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edit/RichEdit controls probably use a 32-bit length value internally.

You probably just have to accept this quirk and treat the return value as a 32-bit integer. This should not be a problem unless you expect to store more than 4gb of text in these controls.

Comment: On Win95/98/ME the internal limit is a 16-bit number, it would be interesting to check what the return value is there, hopefully still a 32-bit number.

Comment: The [Edit_LineIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-edit_lineindex) macro uses `int`, so that supports this idea, but it still feels like a defect.  There doesn't seem to be a way to work around this that won't break if MS fixes this.

Comment: @J... which is why MS can never fix it

Comment: It seems unlikely this will get fixed, the performance of a loaded 4gb file is probably unusable. Even if they fixed it, if you limit yourself to < 4gb the truncation will be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't I expect to use a huge amount of text in the controls but the problem exists when the function is defined to return -1, and the calling code tests for this (if x=-1 then...). This call is made in third party code which I don't want to modify if possible. The issue is that we have a policy to release code built with range and overflow checking turned on, and the Delphi range checking for Int64 to int32 conversions is to trigger on any value greater than $7FFFFFFF.

Comment: @kaj66 write your own `Edit_LineIndex()` function that truncates the `SendMessage()` result to `Integer`, then turn off range/overflow checking for that function